# Setting ZSH_THEME="agnoster" doesn't do anything (macOS Catalina)

Tags: terminal, themes, zsh, zshrc

I just switched from bash to zsh and I want to have the agnoster theme. I have read that to get a theme I just need to set **ZSH_THEME="theme_I_want"** in ~/.zshrc, but when I change the ZSH_THEME to "agnoster" and run source ~/.zshrc nothing happens.

My only line of code inside ~/.zshrc:

```
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**PD**: I already changed my shell from /bin/bash to /bin/zsh and I don't have the .oh-my-zsh file.

Comment: Have you installed oh-my-zsh? `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"` Then try running those commands again. (Changing theme to agnoster in .zshrc and source .zshrc.)

Comment: @GabrielS : This just sets a shell variable. Since it is not even one which has special meaning to Zsh, it can't have any effect.

Comment: @Leif_Lundberg that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielS Since you solved your problem, can you please close your question?

Answer (score 4):

To use the agnoster theme you have to install some fonts. Otherwise you will see some question marks where symbols are supposed to go. Here are the steps to install:

```
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts
cd fonts
./install.sh    ( from terminal / command line )
```

Open iTerm2->Preferences->Profiles->Change Font-> 12pt Meslo LG S DZ Regular for Powerline
After doing that you should see this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I did install it, but that 2nd instruction about changing fonts in my iterm2 is the final piece of the puzzle.